# Insert data from file to table with separator then put it into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a text file in which it is written in this style there data:
`Floran / Marielle`
I would like to retrieve separated by `;` and then store them in a database (SQL Server)
Facts for example table contains firstname (varchar) and name (varchar)
I do not know if I have to store this information in a variable or table or what to do first?

Comment: Which parts do you know how to do?

Comment: some functions that may help you can look up in the manual: explode() fgetcsv() str_getcsv()

Comment: are you related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348641/put-the-contents-of-file-into-an-array-with-delimiter-and-store-it-in-a-database

Answer (score 1):

```
// read file into $data
$data = file_get_contents('names.txt');

// create an array by splitting at every /
$data = explode('/',$data);

// create an SQL statement to insert into a database
$max = count($data);
$sql = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i+=2)
    $sql .= '("' . trim($data[$i]) . '","' . trim($data[$i+1]) . '"),';

$sql = 'INSERT INTO tablename (firstname,name) VALUES ' .trim($sql,',');

// add code for inserting into your db
```

Comment: skip explode use fgetcsv

Comment: @dagon you're right, good idea.